# JavaFX. onMouseEnter с нажатой кнопкой мыши

Tags: javafx, mouse-event

Есть множество объектов одного класса на экране. Определить когда указатель мыши оказывается над каждым объектом или покидает его проблем не составляет - setOnMouseEnter и т.д. При нажатой кнопке мыши эти события не отправляются. Есть ли какие то не хардкорные способы отследить перемещение мыши по объектам с нажатой кнопкой.

Answer (score 1):

Есть стандартный метод итерфейса [MouseMotionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html)

Отрывок кода:

```
// обработка события "перемещения мыши"
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
            // TODO:
            System.out.pringln("Moving mouse at " + me.getX() + ", " + me.getY());
            System.out.pringln("Component: "me.getComponent());
            System.out.pringln("Source: "me.getSource());
            //
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но ничего не понял, если честно. Видимо потому, что забыл упомянуть - все происходит в javaFX.